# NativeScript tns proxy settings file

Tags: proxy, nativescript, nativescript-angular

On a Mac:

- proxy settings are stored at $user_home/.bash_profile or $user_home/.bashrc
- npm proxy settings are stored at $user_home/.npmrc

Which file gets tns proxy settings, When proxy is set using 'tns proxy' command.
$user_home/.tnsrc doesn't have anything related to proxy settings.

Comment: are you using `tns proxy set` ?

Comment: yes. i am using 'tns proxy set'

Comment: Some reason for me proxy settings were stored here  `$user_home/.local/share/.nativescript-cli/proxy-cache.json`